# New Assassin/Thug

Tags: rogue, assassin

I'm working on making a pseudo assassin type class, but one that doesn't lurk in the shadows.  They'll be a "I'm that good that you can't touch me" type of assassin/rogue/tough guy character, but I can't really find anything like that short of using assassin variants with bravado from other classes thrown into it. A lot of the "i'm not afraid to get my hands dirty" attitude, alongside the "what are you going to do about it?" would sum them up.  They're going to be a main part of a large gang in StormReach, and I figure it would be easier for the law to leave them alone, though that's obviously up to my DM

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! You could take the [tour] and visit the [help] to have some guidelines about posting in this website! What game system are you playing? It is not clear what you are asking: if you are trying to homebrew a new class, you should write what you created. If you are searching for ideas about _how_ to play existing classes, I am afraid that this is OT...